# Issue on Selecting Inputs inside a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at following code and let me know why i am not able to get the ID of selected radios by using the `this.id`?

```
<div id="pay" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="mode" id="option1"> Cash
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="mode" id="option2"> Cheque
    </label>
</div>

<script>
$("#pay input:radio").on('click',function(){
 alert(this.id);
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/gt4Qh/

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

If that posted code is, in fact, the *entirety* of your jQuery you've simply forgotten to use the document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code should be in here
});
```

Or you could ensure that your `<script>` is placed before the closing `</body>` tag, both of which approaches ensure the content of the page is loaded and present in the page *before* you try binding event-handlers.

Comment: +1 I agree cuz OP's code can alert id from fiddle when js is fully loaded:http://jsfiddle.net/8r9yd/4/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jQuery code is executed once the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // All your function calls, self-invoked functions, etc
    // Also you define your event handlers here
});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) about the `.ready( handler )`:

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded

Then you need to transform `this` into a jQuery object to access its methods, e.g. `.attr()` like so:  `$(this)`

Since jQuery version 1.7 you may use event delegation by using the `.on()` function.

Again the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#pay input:radio', function() {
            // Instead of using alert(), use the console for debugging
            window.console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`$(this).attr("id")` instead of `this.id`

Comment: And why do you think that this will make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

this will work;

```
$(function(){

     $(document).on('click', '#pay input:radio', function(){

      alert($(this).prop('id'))

   });


})
```

Comment: *Why?* the only change you've made is to make the process of retrieving the `id` *more expensive* and somewhat (albeit marginally) slower.